# inequality of two functions

Tags: inequality, induction

I have the following problem. I need to show that $b(i)>b(i-1)^{i-1}$ for $i>k$ for some $k$. $b$ is the following function: $b(1)=2$ and $b(n)=2^{b(n-1)}$

I tried to do this by induction, but it does not work out:
Take base case $k=2$. Then it works.

Induction hypothesis: for $n$ we have that $b(n)>b(n-1)^{n-1}$.
Then for $b(n+1): b(n+1)=2^{b(n)}$
From our IH we have that $2^{b(n)} > 2^{b(n-1)^{n-1}}$
We can rewrite the right term to $b(n)^{n-1}$.
Now I end up with:
$b(n+1)>b(n)^{n-1}$, whereas I want $b(n+1)>b(n)^n$.

Does anybody have any tips of how to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $b(n) \geqslant n+1$ hence 
$$b(n+1) =2^{b(n)} >2^{b(n-1)^{n-1}} =(2^{b(n-1)})^{b(n-1)^{n-2}} =b(n)^{b(n-1)^{n-2}}\geqslant b(n)^{b(n-1)} \geqslant b(n)^n$$ for $n\geqslant 3.$

Comment: I feel a bit silly, but I can't seem to follow the steps. Could you perhaps add a small explanation for why this holds? Not all of the (in)equalities appear to be trivially true.

Comment: How can you observe that $b(n) \geqslant n+1$ ? I don't really see it..

Comment: By induction we prove that $b(n)\geq n+1,$ we have $b(1)=2\geq 1+1$ and $$b(n+1)=2^{b(n)} \geq 2^{n+1}\geq n+2 =(n+1)+1$$